# Even if the address of the list changes, does the address value of the property remain the same?

Tags: android, kotlin, arraylist

Currently, I am making a task in `Android` that changes the `unit value` of the `list` according to the `toggle button` and shows the list with the changed value.

I am observing the list using a `ViewModel` and `LiveData`.

So i use `toList()` to return a `new list` and overwrite the `old list` to observe the values.

However, the screen is not updated even though it has returned a new list.

I've tried debugging and I'm getting some incomprehensible results.

Obviously, the address values ​​of the old list and the new list are different, but even the `unit` of the `old list` has changed.

What happened?

Even if the addresses of Lists are different, do the values ​​of the old list and the new list change at the same time because the properties refer to the same place?

---

*I'll show you the minimal code.*

***Fragment***

```
// Change Unit
toggleButton.addOnButtonCheckedListener { _, checkedId, isChecked ->
    if(isChecked) {
        when(checkedId) {
            R.id.kg -> vm.changeUnit("kg")
            R.id.lb -> vm.changeUnit("lbs")
        }
    }
}

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    vm.items.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) { newList ->
        adapter.submitList(newList)
    }
}
```

***WorkoutSetInfo***

```
@Entity(
    foreignKeys = [
        ForeignKey(
            entity = Workout::class,
            parentColumns = arrayOf("workoutId"),
            childColumns = arrayOf("parentWorkoutId"),
            onDelete = ForeignKey.CASCADE
        )
    ]
)
data class WorkoutSetInfo(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    val id: Long = 0,
    val set: Int,
    var weight: String = "",
    var reps: String = "",
    var unit: String = "kg",
    val parentWorkoutId: Long = 0
)
```

***Adapter***

```
class DetailAdapter
    : ListAdapter<WorkoutSetInfo, DetailAdapter.ViewHolder>(DetailDiffCallback()) {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        return ViewHolder(
            ItemRoutineDetailBinding.inflate(
                LayoutInflater.from(parent.context),
                parent,
                false
            )
        )
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.bind(currentList[position])
    }

    inner class ViewHolder(val binding: ItemRoutineDetailBinding) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {
        private var weightTextWatcher: TextWatcher? = null
        private var repTextWatcher: TextWatcher? = null

        fun bind(item: WorkoutSetInfo) {

            binding.set.text = item.set.toString()
            binding.weight.removeTextChangedListener(weightTextWatcher)
            binding.unit.text = item.unit
            binding.rep.removeTextChangedListener(repTextWatcher)

            weightTextWatcher = object : TextWatcher {
                override fun beforeTextChanged(p0: CharSequence?, p1: Int, p2: Int, p3: Int) { }
                override fun onTextChanged(p0: CharSequence?, p1: Int, p2: Int, p3: Int) { }
                override fun afterTextChanged(w: Editable?) {
                    if(!binding.weight.hasFocus())
                        return
                    item.weight = w.toString()
                }
            }

            repTextWatcher = object : TextWatcher {
                override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) { }
                override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) { }
                override fun afterTextChanged(r: Editable?) {
                    if(!binding.rep.hasFocus())
                        return
                    item.reps = r.toString()
                }
            }

            binding.apply {
                weight.setTextIfDifferent(item.weight)
                weight.addTextChangedListener(weightTextWatcher)
                rep.setTextIfDifferent(item.reps)
                rep.addTextChangedListener(repTextWatcher)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**DiffUtil***

```
class DetailDiffCallback : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<WorkoutSetInfo>() {
    override fun areItemsTheSame(
        oldItem: WorkoutSetInfo,
        newItem: WorkoutSetInfo
    ): Boolean  {
       return (oldItem.id == newItem.id)
    }

    override fun areContentsTheSame(
        oldItem: WorkoutSetInfo,
        newItem: WorkoutSetInfo
    ): Boolean {
        return oldItem == newItem
    }
}
```

***ViewModel***

```
class DetailViewModel(application: Application, title: String) : ViewModel() {
    private val workoutDao = DetailDatabase.getDatabase(application)!!.workoutDao()
    private val repository: WorkoutRepository = WorkoutRepository(workoutDao, title)
    private val _items: MutableLiveData<List<WorkoutSetInfo>> = MutableLiveData()
    val items = _items

    fun changeUnit(unit: String) {
        repository.changeUnit(unit)
        _items.postValue(repository.getList())
    }

    fun addSet() {
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO){
            repository.add()
            _items.postValue(repository.getList())
        }
    }

    fun deleteSet() {
        repository.delete()
        _items.postValue(repository.getList())
    }

    fun save() {
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            repository.save()
        }
    }
}
```

***Repository***

```
class WorkoutRepository(private val workoutDao : WorkoutDao, title: String) {
    private val workout = Workout(title = title)
    private val setInfoList = ArrayList<WorkoutSetInfo>()

    fun changeUnit(unit: String) {
        setInfoList.map { setInfo -> 
            setInfo.unit = unit
        }
    }
    
    fun add() {
        val item = WorkoutSetInfo(set = setInfoList.size + 1)
        setInfoList.add(item)
    }

    fun delete() {
        if(setInfoList.size != 0)
            setInfoList.removeLast()
        return
    }

    fun save() {
        val workoutId = workoutDao.insertWorkout(workout)
        val newWorkoutSetInfoList = setInfoList.map { setInfo ->
            setInfo.copy(parentWorkoutId = workoutId)
        }
        workoutDao.insertSetInfoList(newWorkoutSetInfoList)
    }
    
    fun getList() : List<WorkoutSetInfo> = setInfoList.toList()
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd need to post your observer code for any help with why it's not updating.

As for the weird behaviour, `setInfoList` contains a few `WorkoutSetInfo` objects, right? Let's call them A, B and C. When you call `setInfoList.toList()` you're creating a new *container*, which holds the same references to objects A, B and C. Because it's a separate list, you can add and remove items without affecting the original list, but any changes to the *objects* that both share will be reflected in both lists - because they're both looking at the same thing.

So when you do `setInfoList.map { setInfo -> setInfo.unit = unit }` (which should be `forEach` really, `map` creates a new list you're discarding) you're modifying A, B and C. So every list you've made that contains those objects will see those changes, including your old list.

Basically if you want each list to be independent, when you modify the list you need to create new instances of the items, which means copying your `WorkoutSetInfo` objects to create new ones, instead of updating the current ones. If it's a `data class` then you can do that fairly easily (so long as you don't have nested objects that need copying themselves):

```
// var so we can replace it with a new list
private var setInfoList = listOf<WorkoutSetInfo>()

fun changeUnit(unit: String) {
    // create a new list, copying each item with a change to the unit property
    setInfoList = setInfoList.map { setInfo ->
        setInfo.copy(unit = unit)
    }
}
```

You don't need to do `toList()` on `getList` anymore, since you're just passing the current version of the list, and that list will never change (because you'll just create a new one). Meaning you don't need that function, you can just make `setInfoList` public - and because I changed it to `listOf` which creates an immutable `List`, it's safe to pass around because it can't be modified.

---

The `WorkoutSetInfo` objects inside that list *could* still be modified externally though (e.g. by changing one of the items' `unit` value), so instead of making a new copy when you call `changeUnit`, you might want to do it when you call `getList` instead:

```
class WorkoutRepository(private val workoutDao : WorkoutDao, title: String) {
    private val workout = Workout(title = title)
    private val setInfoList = ArrayList<WorkoutSetInfo>()
    // store the current unit here
    private var currentUnit = "kg"

    fun changeUnit(unit: String) {
        currentUnit = unit
    }
    
    // return new List
    fun getList() : List<WorkoutSetInfo> = setInfoList.map { it.copy(unit = currentUnit) }
}
```

Now everything that calls `getList` gets a unique list with unique objects, so they're all separate from each other. And if you don't actually need to store the current `unit` value, you could pass it in to `getList` instead of having a `changeUnit` function:

```
fun getList(unit: String) = setInfoList.map { it.copy(unit = unit) }
```

Comment: Updated the code. But even if I use copy, the screen is still not updated..

Comment: @ybybyb is ``submitList`` in your adapter calling ``notifyDataSetChanged`` or anything like that? You'll have to post your adapter code too. Also put a ``Log`` call in your observer, then you'll know if it's triggering or not (if it is, the problem is in your adapter)

Comment: Sorry, I added Adapter and DiffUtil code.

Comment: @ybybyb your adapter looks fine, so I assume it's just the original issue again - if you make a basic copy of a list, it contains *the exact same object instances* as the original. Any changes you make to A, B and C, the "old" list in the adapter sees those changes, because it's referring to the same objects. And when you try to diff the new list, `[A, B, C]` with the old list `[A, B, C]`, they're the same (two lists are equal if they contain the same items in the same order) so your adapter sees no reason to update - nothing's changed, y'know?

Comment: If you've made the changes like I said (creating a new list with ``map`` and using ``copy`` to change the units of each item) then it should work fine, because you're not changing the old list or its items (that the adapter has a copy of). Whenever you change the list, you make a copy so the old versions aren't affected. That way, your diff should be getting a new list, with new items, and the old list shouldn't have been changed at all. You should probably set a breakpoint in there somewhere and debug it, look at the lists and see if they look right

Comment: I'm really sorry. I was making a really small mistake.
I just kept running `setInfoList.map { copy }` .

You should have done `updatedList = setInfoList.map { copy }` according to the code you wrote down. I haven't created a property that refers to the `new list` returned by `map { }`.

I was expecting `setInfoList` itself to refer to the `new list` automatically when I proceed with `setInfoList.map { }` .

Comment: @ybybyb yeah ``map`` produces a new list - you were using it in a weird way in your original code, discarding the transformed list and using the map function to create side effects. That's why I said it should be a ``forEach`` if you were doing that - it's clearer that you're poking at the original items, ``map`` is for transforming each item into a new item (which is definitely what you want here!)

Comment: thanks. I'm sorry, but I'm going to ask you one more thing.

Reading your replies, I have a question.

Assume that `setInfoList` has objects `A,B,C` .
When you run `getList()`
For `setInfoList` it will return a list with `new containers`.

But the objects in the `new list` still hold the same references to `A, B, and C`. (What you described so far.)

First, let's look at `delete()` in the `Repository`.
Here, executing `setInfoList.removeLast()` will remove the last object `C`.

Comment: After `delete()` of Repository is executed, `postValue(repository.getList())` will be executed in `ViewModel`.

If so, my expectation is that the `ViewModel` and `List` of `Repository` have different `containers`, but refer to the same object `A, B, and C`, so the screen should not be updated.

Because i thinks that if `C` in the `old List` is deleted, `C` in the `new List` will also be deleted automatically.

But my screen erases very well.

For what reason?

Comment: @ybybyb I can't really get into a discussion about it, but if your internal repository list has A, B and C in it, and you copy that (list2), then you have two different list objects (containers), but they both contain the same objects. If you then delete the last item in the repo list, then it only contains A and B. List2 still contains A, B and C, so those lists aren't equal (but the first 2 items in each are the same, and the items are what the diff looks at to work out what's changed)

Comment: If you're unsure about any of this, make sure you know how equality works for normal classes (has to be the same object), for data classes (same object type & same values for the constructor properties), lists (same items in the same order, i.e. `list1[0] == list2[0]` etc) and then how `DiffUtil` works. Equality comes down to how the `equals` function is implemented for a class. If you `copy` an instance of a data class, but without changing any of its property values (which you should be here, that's the point of making a new copy!) you'll get a different object that still `==` the original

Comment: Ah, so `list.remove` doesn't delete the reference value itself, it just deletes the item from the list, right?

Are you saying that `list.remove` doesn't delete the `heap area`?

It just deletes from the list, so one list still has `C` and the other doesn't.

Comment: @ybybyb it's like any other object on the JVM, so long as something has a reference to it, it won't be garbage collected (that's slightly simplifying it but you get the idea). If an object is deleted from *list1*, but *list2* also has a reference to it, it's still live, so it won't be deleted. Which is what you'd expect, right? If two lists refer to the same object in memory, and you remove the reference in one list, the thing shouldn't disappear from the other! It might be worth going through a basic Java tutorial to get these concepts down, it's a lot easier to reason about once you know